# Javascript change or load

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below Javascript code is used to display content depending on what a user has chosen from a drop down - it fires when the user changes the value in the dropdown and displays the code in display.php in #disp.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#choose').change(function() {
            if($(this).val() != '') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: 'display.php',
                    data: { 'value' : $(this).val() } ,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#disp").html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that, sometimes, I have the drop down prepopulated when the form loads with a choice already activated and, as the value of #choose is not changing, the javascript is not called. I could use load(function() but then it wouldn't trigger upon changing.

How can I make the same code fire when the user changes content but also upon loading where the value is not 0/null/blank within the same call?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Trigger the change function programatically:

```
$('#choose').change(function() {
  // your code
}).change(); // will trigger when DOM is ready
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to do anything differently - it works fine for change (as before) but upon loading the page with a value prepopulated in #choose, #disp is not shown?

Comment: @Jason: debug it, the change event will be firing. I'm guessing the problem lies with getting the value or the ajax response

Comment: It is working now - I was only passing a value into the option in the select so it didn't do anything as #choose had no value. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
var chooseVal = $('#choose').val();
if(chooseVal != null || chooseVal != 0) $('#choose').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 1):

Separate the call in a different function and then execute it onload. Something like this...

```
function onchange() {
    if($(this).val() != '') {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'display.php',
            data: { 'value' : $(this).val() } ,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#disp").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#choose').change(function() {
        onchange.call(this);
    });
    onchange.call(document.getElementById("choose"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('#choose').change();` just after you prepopluate the select box.This should trigger the change handler.